# Scroll UITextView To Bottom

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am making a an app that has a `UITextView` and a button.

When I click the button some text will add in the `UITextView`.

But when clicking the button, I wan't to scroll down to the bottom of the text field so the user can see the last text added.

How to make the `UITextView` to scroll down to the bottom?

I tried:

```
int numLines = LogTextView.contentSize.height / LogTextView.font.lineHeight+1;
NSLog(@"%d",numLines);

NSUInteger length = self.LogTextView.text.length;
self.LogTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, length);
```

but it will not work...

I also tried:

```
self.LogTextView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(length,0);
```

Comment: First of all is text view because a UITextView, because the text field doesn't have a scroll. ;) And maybe you could use `scrollRangeToVisible` method :)

Comment: as @danypata questioned, is this a uitextview, or a uitextfield in a uiscrollview? you referenced both text field and text view in the question.

Comment: @andrewlattis the question is about `UITextView` which is a sub of `UIScrollView` which has `contentSize` as a property.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use the following code if you are talking about UITextView:

```
-(void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView {
     if(textView.text.length > 0 ) {
        NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1);
        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];
     }

}
```

**SWIFT 4:**

```
func scrollTextViewToBottom(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.count > 0 {
        let location = textView.text.count - 1
        let bottom = NSMakeRange(location, 1)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: DON'T FORGET TO ADD
[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[textView setScrollEnabled:YES];

Comment: @ofirmalachi, did you mean to write conflicting statements in your comment above?

Comment: @stuckj I think what he meant what disable scrolling when it is still scrolling down and the enable it again after it is finished. CMIIW.

Comment: Note using `scrollRangeToVisible` with large texts may make `UITextView` freeze because of animation. Better use `contentOffset` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42478029/3004003, but set `animated` to `false`

Answer (score 19):

Try this if you have problem on iOS 7 or above. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20989956/971070).

```
- (void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length, 0);
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
    // an iOS bug, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20989956/971070
    [textView setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: IOS 13 and the bug is still here!

Answer (score 12):

With Swift 3

```
let bottom = self.textView.contentSize.height - self.textView.bounds.size.height
self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true)
```

Comment: It should work. Where are you using this code? Make sure you're using it after textView has been loaded.

Comment: It's after viewDidAppear, and textview is fully loaded, with content. Might be related to the fact that the textview's content is larger than the screen's bounds by a large margin

Comment: I've just re-verified and it's working just fine. I've created a new single view project, drag and drop a textView with default size and default text, connected outlet, put this code inside viewDidAppear. And it correctly scrolled to bottom.

Comment: It's better to add check if bottom positive or not, because if it is negative then there is no need to change contentOffset.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (iOS11). My text spans many lines and uses a custom font.

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 5

```
extension UITextView {
    func simple_scrollToBottom() {
        let textCount: Int = text.count
        guard textCount >= 1 else { return }
        scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: textCount - 1, length: 1))
    }
}

// Usage
textView.simple_scrollToBottom()
```

Comment: Excellent recommendation!  Works really well.  Placed the extension at bottom of code after class }  and then used the  //Usage. code in the button Action.

Comment: change this for swift 5 scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: textCount - 1, length: 1))

Comment: Thanks @AMAN77 I have inserted your changes.

Comment: It is need to be called by delay after set text

Answer (score 5):

Make a range, specifying encoding, to the last character, then scroll to that range
Something other than utf8 might be appropriate depending on your content

```
let range = NSMakeRange(self.textView.text.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8), 0);
self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range);
```

Comment: The best solution of all with the minimum lag!

Comment: this works on iOS 14.4 as well. smooth and no issues at all

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement a delegate method. The code below checks whether a newline has been entered and, if so, scrolls to the bottom of the textView:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, textView.contentSize.height);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me! :D

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.textView.contentSize.height - self.textView.bounds.size.height);
[self.description1 setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: This works well for when you need to do this without animation (with animated:NO of course). Note that you might want to add in a `max(0, ...` to scroll down only when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As a generic approach for scrolling to bottom, it can be done on a UIScrollView.

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToBottom() {
        let contentHeight = contentSize.height - frame.size.height
        let contentoffsetY = max(contentHeight, 0)
        setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentoffsetY), animated: true)
    }
}
```

This will work on all descendants of UIScrollView like UITextView, UITableView etc..

Answer (score 3):

```swift
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(..<textView.text.endIndex, in: textView.text))
```

This solution does a couple of notable things slightly different:

- Utilizes the `String.Index` interface (likely more performant than e.g. `.count`)
- Uses a `PartialRangeUpTo` which avoids an explicit range start position, reducing the code to a clean one-liner

Answer (score 1):

The Swift version of [@Hong Duan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33194525/4770877)

```
func scrollTextViewToBottom(textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.count > 0 {
        let location = textView.text.count - 1
        let bottom = NSMakeRange(location, 1)
        textView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)

        // an iOS bug, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20989956/971070
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```