# UITextView contentOffset not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my app. I need to change it's content offset dynamically every time a new string is appended. The code bellow works fine on iOS 6 and earlier versions, but not on iOS 7.

```
TextViewText.text = [TextViewText.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:RecentWordRange withString:string];
   newStringLen = string.length;
   [TextViewText setSelectedRange: NSMakeRange(RecentWordRange.location+string.length, 0)];
   [TextViewText setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0,0) animated:NO];
   [TextViewText setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
```

what is change in IOS7 for setContentOffset?

Comment: what is the variable contentOffset containing?

Comment: contentOffset   = TextViewText.contentOffset;

Comment: This is an iOS 7 bug.  My workaround is here and it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124037/scroll-to-bottom-of-uitextview-erratic-in-ios-7-with-many-updates/19339716#19339716

Comment: This is an iOS 7 bug.  My workaround is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124037/scroll-to-bottom-of-uitextview-erratic-in-ios-7-with-many-updates/19339716#19339716

Answer (score 2):

Use UITextView's `textContainerInset` for what would be `insets`, and use (UIEdgeInsets)`contentInset` for what would be (CGPoint)`contentOffset`.

No idea why someone decided this was the best way to handle UITextView offsetting, but this is working for me.

Also note that there is a strange bug that doesn't accept insets on the textView unless there is a right and left offset. So make sure left/right UIEdgeInsets are greater than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I resolved a similar problem in iOS 8. I Replaced text in the text view and it jumped around. Using the UITextRange related method helped.

```
UITextRange *RecentWordRange = TextViewText.selectedTextRange;
[TextViewText replaceRange:RecentWordRange withText:string];
```