# Scroll to the bottom of textView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I made a button that adds some text to a textView and I want it to automatically scroll to the bottom as it is pressed so that user would be able to see the new text added.

I can't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698638/textview-scroll-textview-to-bottom) solution in Swift because I don't know Objective-C.
Does anyone know how can I scroll to the bottom of a textView in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: if the `textView` is scrollable you can scroll? What exactly you mean? Have you tried it before posting?Show some code please:)

Comment: what version of os you are using?

Comment: `self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))` try this where for range put the end of the `textView`

Comment: Try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124037/scroll-to-bottom-of-uitextview-erratic-in-ios-7)

Comment: @Korpel I edited my question. I want to scroll programmatically. Imagine a textView full of characters. I want to press a button and scroll to the bottom of this textView programmatically. You can see the Objective-C solution in the link above.

Comment: @Barsam have a look at my second comment and see if that helps you out.`self.textView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(-1, 1))`

Comment: @PK20 Xcode 7 , iOS 8.4 and Swift 2.0

Comment: good. Then the solution is at the bottom of the link I provided. Regards

Answer (score 22):

Tried both content offset and scrolltoview solutions, get mixed results and choppy scrolling; having looked around the below seemed to work and produce consistent scrolling to the bottom when needed.

In viewdidload:

```
self.storyTextView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
```

Then when needed:

```
let stringLength:Int = self.storyTextView.text.characters.count
self.storyTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(stringLength-1, 0))
```

Comment: Wow I was having a hard time with choppy scrolling and weird glyph cutoffs sometimes and turns out `.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false` is the silver bullet, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Swift 4

```
let bottom = NSMakeRange(textLog.text.count - 1, 1)
textLog.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
```

Swift 3

```
let bottom = NSMakeRange(textLog.text.characters.count - 1, 1)
textLog.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
```

Update: thanks @AntoineRucquoy for Swift 4 reminder!

Comment: Since Swift 4.x and in order to avoid a deprecated warning, use textLog.text.count rather than textLog.text.characters.count :-)

Answer (score 5):

Simply, where `myTextView` is the `UITextView` in question:

```
let bottom = myTextView.contentSize.height

myTextView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true) // Scrolls to end
```

Answer (score 4):

So if you click the link you posted the accepted answer shows this objective-C code:

```
-(void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView 
{
  if(textView.text.length > 0 ) 
  {
    NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1);
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];
  }
}
```

So your challenge is to convert that code to Swift.

Break it into pieces and tackle them one at a time. First, the method definition itself.

The method is called scrollTextViewToBottom. It takes a UITextView as a parameter, and does not return a result. How would you write that method definition in Swift?

Next look that the body of the method. The if statement should be exactly the same in Swift.
The creation of an NSRange is all but identical. You just need to change it a little bit:

```
let bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 1)
```

The part that's probably the hardest for somebody who doesn't know Objective-C is the method call. It's sending the message scrollRangeToVisible to the object `textView`. The parameter passed is `bottom`. See if you can rewrite that line in Swift. Then put the whole thing together.

Comment: So who downvoted my answer, and why? I'm trying to teach the OP how to solve these sorts of problems for himself rather than giving him the converted code. In the long run learning how to figure this out for yourself is a lot more helpful than having somebody else spoon-feed you finished code.

Comment: i totally agree with you Sir.Your answer is giving legit steps to help the OP.Upvoted

Comment: I disagree, this is a very non-standard way to scroll a text view. Most iOS are most familiar with using `contentOffset`. Not to mention, `NSRange` will most likely be deprecated in the future in favor of Swift's `Range`.

Comment: I answered in terms of the code that the OP found in order to provide a lesson in how to translate Objective-C to Swift. I will bet a large sum of money that NSRange will not be deprecated in the next 2 or 3 years since it is widely used in Objective-C code, and Objective-C is going to be around for a very long time.

Comment: Your solution of using the textView's contentOffset property and `setContentOffset:animated:` is good, but I felt that teaching the OP how to understand Objective-C was important.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following in an app that scrolls to the bottom automatically when text is added:

First when initializing your textView, do the following:

```
textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
```

Then add the following observer method:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    var bottom = textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height
    if bottom < 0 {
        bottom = 0
    }
    if textView.contentOffset.y != bottom {
        textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true)
    }
}
```

setting **allowsNonContiguousLayout** to **false** fixed contentSize problems for me.

Adding the **contentSize** observer will observe for any new changes in the **contentSize** of the textView and call the **-observeValue(forKeyPath...)** function when changes are made.

In the **-observeValue(...)** function, we first get the **bottom** (y contentOffset when fully scrolled to the bottom). We then check if that value is negative, meaning that the contentSize height is smaller than the textView frame height and you can't really do any scrolling. If you try to programmatically scroll with that negative value, it will cause that infamous jitter that many people know and love. So to avoid this jitter we simply set the value to what it already should be, **0** or you can also just **return**.

Then we just test to see if the **contentOffset** doesn't already equal the **bottom** value, we give it that new value. This avoids setting the **contentOffset** when it doesn't need to be set.

Answer (score 2):

Language:Swift

Follow steps as below:
    //Declare

```
@IBOutlet weak var trTextDataRead: UITextView!
```

//Cunstom method

```
func insertTextView(text: String){
 //Insert text
 trTextDataRead.text.append(text)  

 //Scroll to the end  
 let btm = NSMakeRange(trTextDataRead.text.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8), 0)  
 trTextDataRead.scrollRangeToVisible(btm)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with the UITextView's attributedText property:

in viewDidLoad()

```
self.storyTextView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
```

in your scrolling method

```
let stringLength:Int = self.storyTextView.attributedText.string.characters.count
self.storyTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(stringLength-1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```
private func textViewScrollToBottom() {
    let bottomRange = NSMakeRange(self.myTextView.text.count - 1, 1)

    self.myTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottomRange)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` has a property `contentOffsent`. You can either set `textView.contentOffset` or `textView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)`

For example if the `contentSize` of your text view is `(100, 500)` but the height of the text view is only 100, then to scroll to the bottom, set the `contentOffset` property to `(0, 400)` (this is for a vertical text view). More generically the formula for scrolling to the bottom is `textView.contentSize.height-textView.height`. Every time your button is pressed, set the offset.

I would also really recommend reading the documentation and trying to figure it out. Swift and iOS is quite well documented and a question like this is easily searchable via Google.

Edit: This works because `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`.

Sidenote: I wrote a [`UITextView`](https://github.com/startupthekid/VerticalTextView) subclass where you can set the vertical text alignment so if you set the text alignment to `.Bottom`, the text will align with the bottom of the view.

```
class TextView: UITextView {

    enum VerticalAlignment: Int {
        case Top = 0, Middle, Bottom
    }

    var verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment = .Middle

    //override contentSize property and observe using didSet
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            let textView = self
            let height = textView.bounds.size.height
            let contentHeight:CGFloat = contentSize.height
            var topCorrect: CGFloat = 0.0
            switch(self.verticalAlignment){
            case .Top:
                textView.contentOffset = CGPointZero //set content offset to top
           case .Middle:
                topCorrect = (height - contentHeight * textView.zoomScale)/2.0
                topCorrect = topCorrect < 0 ? 0 : topCorrect
                textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -topCorrect)
           case .Bottom:
                topCorrect = textView.bounds.size.height - contentHeight
                topCorrect = topCorrect < 0 ? 0 : topCorrect
                textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -topCorrect)
            }
            if contentHeight >= height { //if the contentSize is greater than the height
                topCorrect = contentHeight - height //set the contentOffset to be the
                topCorrect = topCorrect < 0 ? 0 : topCorrect //contentHeight - height of textView
                textView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: topCorrect)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - UIView

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let size = self.contentSize //forces didSet to be called
        self.contentSize = size
    }
}
```

In the above example (pulled directly from my subclass), you'll notice I make extensive use of the `contentOffset` property. I do some calculations to figure out where the offset should be based on the vertical alignment property and then set the content offset property according (which is how you programmatically scroll with a scroll view)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people are explaining how to scroll to the bottom, but one thing to note is that this won't work if you place it in `viewDidLoad`. For example: I needed to use this to scroll a log to the bottom when the page loaded. In order to do this, I had to implement the following code

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_logTextView setText:[Logger loadLogText]];
}

- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [_logTextView
     setContentOffset:CGPointMake(
                          0.0,
                          _logTextView.contentSize.height
                        - _logTextView.frame.size.height
                      )
             animated:NO
    ];
}
```

The actual scrolling of the UITextView cannot be done in `viewDidLoad`.

In my `viewDidLoad` implementation I set the text for the text box.

In my `viewDidLayoutSubviews` implementation I set the content offset for the UITextView by generating a CGPoint using the height of the text views content minus the height of the text view itself. This way, when it scrolls to the bottom, the bottom of the text is not at the top of the box and instead, the bottom of the text is at the bottom of the box.

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5 - with extension to UITextView + avoid slow scroll in large texts (this issue killed my main Thread)

```
extension UITextView {

    func scrollToBottom() {
        // IMPORTANT - only use (text as NSString) to get the length, since text.length is O(N) and it will kill the main thread.
        let length = (text as NSString).length
        if length > 1 {
            scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(length - 1, 1))
        }
    }
}
```