# iOS: Scrolling text view to bottom programmatically creates a large white space after the text

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift3.2

I am trying to load the contents of a file to a `TextView` on `viewDidLoad()` of a `ViewController`. I want the user to see the last content loaded from the file, so I tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698638/scroll-uitextview-to-bottom).

```
let bottom = textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height
textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated:true)
```

The textview will scroll down but creates a large white space if we scroll down again.

Comment: is your controller embedded to tabViewcontroller ?

Comment: No, its a regular ViewController pushed to navigation stack

Comment: what happens if you remove this line **(let bottom = textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true)
)**  can you share screenshot or elaboration ?

Comment: @KKRocks If I remove the line then the scroll will remain on top of the content and the user will have to scroll down for the last line in the textView

Comment: then try this solution : textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This minor change, resolved my issue:

```
let bottom = CGPoint(x: 0, y: textView.contentSize.height - textView.frame.size.height)
textView.setContentOffset(bottom, animated: false)
```

Posting my answer, so that someone else find this helpful. 
Thanku all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

By updating the content offset you are actually adding that much offset to the content of scrollview. Here with

```
let bottom = textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.size.height textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: bottom), animated: true)
```

these you are adding extra space at the bottom. So for automatically scrolling the content to the last line try using `scrollRangeToVisible` function. Like in the top rated answer you have mentioned in your question that you have used to scroll the textview to the last line.

Comment: I did tried this (scrollRangeToVisible) solution before this one and it was working, But the problem I found with this was that the scrolling appears choppy.
Even though with setContentOffset() I am getting the scroll right, but this (question) issue persist

Comment: So when you were using scrollRangeToVisible was it creating blank spaces in the bottom like how you are getting right now ?